# Why this simple query is not working giving error

Tags: mysql

I am tired to find out why this simple query not working.

```
SELECT image_url FROM allimages WHERE for='projects'
```

Please help me. I have checked connection with mysql, it's ok and other queries working.

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work ?

Comment: For starters, I recommend against having a column named `for`.  Don't use even _potentially_ reserved words for column names.  Give columns descriptive names which actually have contextual meaning.

Comment: the code highlighting on stackoverflow already shows what's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` is [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql, but Mysql allows it. You need to enclose such reserved words in backticks(`)  while using them in query.

Try:

```
SELECT image_url FROM allimages WHERE `for`='projects'
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `for` is a [reserved](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) word in mysql. You can quote them so that sql doesn't mistake them for keywords like below.

```
SELECT image_url FROM allimages WHERE `for`='projects'
```

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess for the lack of details in your question, you are using `FOR` as a column name, which according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html is a reserved word in mysql

Need to enclose:

```
SELECT image_url FROM allimages WHERE `for`='projects'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT image_url FROM allimages WHERE `for`='projects'
```

Since `for` is a reserved word, as @Interstellar_Coder pointed out.